# Facebook share open graph method opens empty pop-up for mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, share, facebook-graph-api, opengraph

[image: Это экран для мобильного]

[image: Второй экран показывает, как окно выглядит на десктопе]

Когда я открываю страницу для Facebook share dialog, она выглядит пустой 
Я инспектирую элемент и нахожу, что страница имеет содержимое, но высота сгенерированного фейсбуком блока iframe body = 0px

Мой код:

```
//Create a new Graph Object
FB.api(
    'me/objects/video.other',
    'post', {
      'object': {
          'type': 'video.other',
          'url': fileUrl,
          'secure_url': fileUrl,
          'video': fileUrl,
          'image': imageUrl,
          'title': title,
          'description': shareUrl
      }
    },

    //Call the FB Share dialog - referencing newly created object.
    function(response) {
      FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        display: !this.isMobile ? 'popup' : 'touch',
        mobile_iframe: true,
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({              
          object: response.id,
        })
      }, function(response){});
    }
);
```

Comment: Вы находитесь в русскоязычном сегменте StackOverflow. Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: Исправила, спасибо )